# delete strings from text file

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I Have the file with the text strings for nucleotides (`A`, `C`, `G`, `T`). I would like to find specifics strings from a text file and delete them.

For example:

```
ACTGGGCTGTCCAACTG     
ACTTCTGGGTCGAACTG     
CCCACTTCTGGGTTCAA
```

And I would like to delete from all lines only this parts `ACT` and `GGG`
Then I will get the file with this strings:

```
CTGTCCAACTG    
TCTTCGAACTG    
CCCTCTTTCAA
```

Comment: could it overlap from a line to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk '{gsub(/ACT|GGG/,"")}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can help you:

```
sed 's/ACT//g; s/GGG//g' inputFile
```

i.e. replace all occurrences of `ACT` and `GGG` with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed -r 's/(ACT|GGG)//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/ACT|GGG//g' your_file
```